# How to start website initialization with dummy request

Tags: c#, windows, service, iis-7, web

I have a website running in IIS7 that takes forever to start up when the app pool recycles (it contains a very large connected service). The app pool recycles every night at midnight, so when the first request is made in the morning, it is EXTREMELY slow to start up. I've been trying to fix this by using a Windows service to hit it with empty POST requests every 2 hours between 12 and 6am and trigger the initialization process, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code for the service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer = new Timer(120 * 60 * 1000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime endTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 6, 0, 0);

        if (DateTime.Now > startTime && DateTime.Now < endTime)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                client.UploadData("https://websitename/KeepAlive.aspx", new byte[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

If anyone could inform me on how to start the initialization process using a service, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: “Every 2 hours"? Did you check your idle timeout setting for the application pool?

Comment: @LexLi Yes, because sometimes it literally times out two or three times before the website starts up. For that reason, I want to hit it with several requests intermittently. And yes, I checked it, but I figured it still wouldn't hurt to hit it a few times instead of just once.

Comment: Your empty request period must be shorter than idle shutdown timeout. Otherwise, it would be a useless mechanism.